# implementing a method in objective-c with Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i am currently following apple's "your first iOS app" tutorial. 
unfortunately i have a problem.

the tutorial gives me some code to add:

```
- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender {
    self.userName = self.textField.text;
    NSString *nameString = self.userName;
    if ([nameString length] == 0) {
        nameString = @"World";
    }
    NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@!", nameString];
    self.label.text = greeting;
}
```

xcode always tells me that there must be a semicolon after "...(id)sender".

but building the app does neither work with the semicolon, nor does it without.
i really hope that someone can help me with this. thanks.

Comment: This app is in developer apple site right..

Comment: Are you sure the error is on this line?

Comment: you might have extra paranthesis or extra line of flower brace

Comment: This can happen if you type this text inside `@interface/@end` - method implementations are not allowed inside interface section.

Comment: oh i must be blind. there is another change greeting:(id)sender at the bottom of the document. i used the wrong one. thank you all for your answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method syntax is correct.

You surely have some syntax error before in the same file.

Provided that you are writing this code inside a implementation (`.m`) file (otherwise that's the issue), check that every other method in the `.m` file has a correct syntax.

Also if you are also declaring the method in the interface file (`.h`) check it's syntax there. It should have the same signature of the implementation.

Bottom line here's how your code should look like:

### Whatever.h

```
@interface Whatever : NSObject

//... other stuff

- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender;

//... other stuff

@end
```

---

### Whatever.m

```
@implementation

//... other stuff

- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender {
    self.userName = self.textField.text;
    NSString *nameString = self.userName;
    if ([nameString length] == 0) {
        nameString = @"World";
    }
    NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@!", nameString];
    self.label.text = greeting;
}

//... other stuff

@end
```

Comment: thank you. i wrote the code between the @ interface and the @ end instead of the @ implementation. you really helped me

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no error on the code you have pasted.Please show your declaration of method on .h.Or any method below or above of above one.May be you are missing end curly braces there.